# cant get tiles to collide with player

Tags: python, pygame

So i'm making a tile based platformer and i cant get collisions to work.

This code in the main loop displays the tiles:

```
tile_rects = []
    y = 0
    for layer in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in layer:
            if tile == '1':
                display.blit(dirt, (x * tile_size, y * tile_size))
            if tile == '2':
                display.blit(grass, (x * tile_size, y * tile_size))
            if tile != '0':
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * tile_size, y * tile_size, tile_size, tile_size))
            x += 1
        y += 1
```

And this code is supposed to make the collisions work but somehow it doesnt, this is in the player class.

```
def collisions(self):
    global tile_rects
    self.rect.x += self.x_vel
    self.rect.y += self.y_vel
    for tile_rect in tile_rects:
        if self.rect.colliderect(tile_rect):
            if abs(tile_rect.top - self.rect.bottom) < 10:
                self.y_vel -= 1
            if abs(tile_rect.bottom - self.rect.top) < 10:
                self.y_vel += 1
            if abs(tile_rect.right - self.rect.left) < 10:
                self.x_vel -= 1
            if abs(tile_rect.left - self.rect.right) < 10:
                self.x_vel += 1
    else: tile_rects = []
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score -1):

You should use `collidelistall()` instead `colliderect()`. It will check if rect if touching any rect of list.